# PUT or DELETE for a logical delete in Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Should we create a PUT or DELETE request for a Logical Delete in Web Api ? I-e setting a flag IsDeleted = 0 or 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The REST school of thought for Web API maps HTTP verbs to operations on resources, and the typical mapping looks like this:

- GET = READ
- POST = CREATE
- PUT = UPDATE (though sometimes PATCH is used in place of PUT, and PATCH may arguably be more correct)
- DELETE = DELETE

The question I'd ask, then, is whether the fact that the delete operation is logical, rather than physical, transparent to the consumer of the API? If the expectation of the API consumer is that they're deleting a record, then I'd use the DELETE verb for the request.

Yes, you *could* use PUT/PATCH to update the IsDeleted field, and it would not be *wrong* per se, but I would look at this from the perspective of what the API consumer expects in order to decide which is right in this situation.